# How to display name of day in Java?

Tags: java, date, time

I am on the beginning chapters for java and this chapter introduces if and else statement and switch. I am not able to print today's day and future day like Sunday, Monday instead it shows the number like 0,1.. When I use if and else statement for future date I cant change it for today's day and vise-versa. I have got this far right now.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise03_05
{
 public static void main (String[] args)
 {
  Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

  System.out.print ("Enter today's day: ");
  int dayNumber = input.nextInt();

  System.out.print ("Enter the number of days elapsed since today: ");
  int daysElapsed = input.nextInt();

// Giving initial value to futureDay
  int futureDay = 0;

  if (daysElapsed < 7)
  futureDay = daysElapsed;
  else 
  futureDay = daysElapsed / 7;

  System.out.println ("Today is " + dayNumber + " and the future day is " + futureDay);
 }
}
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: @Ray how to print out the text of days like Monday or tuesday, instead of their numeric value. Pretty clear tbf.

Comment: If you are new one to java, start to use Joda time, since it is better, simpler and it is used in java 8

Comment: @win_wave, What is the point of using Joda when OP can directly use Java 8

Comment: I do not know what version of java is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct a GregorianCalendar with the year, month and day, then query it to find the name of the day. Something like this:

```
    String days[] ={"Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday"};
    int year = 2014;
    int month = 6;
    int dayOfMonth = 25;
    Calendar myCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, dayOfMonth);
    System.out.print(days[myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest basic way for you to to that is define an array of strings with the days names and call them with the indexes you already have:

```
String days[] ={"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"};
```

So instead of `dayNumber` you call `days[dayNumber]`.

Ex: `System.out.println(days[0]);` will output `Monday`

Answer (score -1):

There is no inherent translation between a number and a day. You need to program the translation manually.

Since your chapter includes the use of switch, you should look into how you can use this construct to set the name of the variable.

You will need something like

```
String dayName;
switch (<a variable) {
<a number of switch branches>
}
<a print statement that uses the dayName variable>
```